# Transit visa for 5 hours layover in Chicago (USA)

Tags: usa, transit, indian-citizens, us-airways

I am from India and I have Canadian student visa, i booked a ticket with British airways which has 2 layover 1 st in London and 2 nd in Chicago (USA). So ,do I need transit visa during the 5 hours layover in Chicago airport? My final destination is Toronto (Canada).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All visitors transiting the US have to actually enter the US, going through passport control, baggage reclaim and customs.

In your case, this means you need a visa for the US. You may apply either for a [transit visa (C)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html) or a [regular visitor visa (B1/B2)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html).

Comment: Yes, there is such a thing as a transit visa: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah indeed, didn't know that. Corrected.